# Making the CSS popup stick to the top of the div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Guys take a look at the attached image. Kinda difficult to explain so attaching image.

[image]

What I'm looking for is, when you hover over the flag icon, a pop-up appears. It's a simple CSS popup. Basically, there's a wrap containing the icon and the popup. The popup is absolutely positioned. The wrap is relatively positioned. The popup has `top:0`. So it starts from the top of the wrap div. What i want is, the popup should stick to the top of the wrap div (from the triangle). And the popup's height is unknown, it depends on the content.

```
<div class="bjper_iconwrap">
   <span id="bjhoverimg" class="icon-flag"></span>
   <div id="bjhoverpop" class="bjoffersbigpop">
   <img class="pinktri" src="/images/pink_triangle.png">
   <p>% Special Offer</p>
   <ul>
      <li><small>£5 Voucher</small>: <small>Buy 10 VCHR get 10 SIMs free</small></li>          
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>

.bjper_iconwrap {
  position: relative;
}
.bjoffersbigpop {
  background: #d1005c;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -47px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the bottom to start at the top instead of using `top:0` use `bottom:100%;` and then `margin-top` minus the size of the arrow:

```css
.bjoffersbigpop {
  background: #d1005c;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:100%;         /*remove top and replace with bottom*/
  margin-top:-20px;    /*minus the size of your arrow - optional*/
  left: -47px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put the popup inside the flag:

```
<div class="bjper_iconwrap">
   <span id="bjhoverimg" class="icon-flag">
      <div id="bjhoverpop" class="bjoffersbigpop">
   </span>
   <img class="pinktri" src="/images/pink_triangle.png">
   <p>% Special Offer</p>
   <ul>
      <li><small>£5 Voucher</small>: <small>Buy 10 VCHR get 10 SIMs free</small></li>          
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

And have it positioned by `bottom` instead of `top`:

```
.bjoffersbigpop {
  background: #d1005c;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -47px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var height= $('.bjoffersbigpop').height();
  $('.bjoffersbigpop').css('top', - height + 'px');
})
```

Comment: @Pete, i forget the minus mark (-), and i think it works now